# One pair or fewer

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a list of positive integers, give the longest contiguous sublist which contains at most 1 pair of identical items.  In the case of a tie return any of the solutions.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize your source code with answers being scored in bytes.

### Test cases

```
[] -> []
[1,2,3] -> [1,2,3]
[1,2,2,3] -> [1,2,2,3]
[2,2,3,2,4] -> [2,3,2,4]
[1,2,1,3,2] -> [2,1,3,2]
[1,2,3,1,4,1,2,3,4,5,1] -> [1,2,3,4,5,1]
[1,2,3,2] -> [1,2,3,2]
```

Comment: I don't understand, is this submission asking us to rewrite the filterDuplicates functions or something?

Comment: @logic It is asking you to write a program or function which takes a list of positive integers and gives the lonest contiguous sublist which contains 1 or fewer pairs of identical elements.  If you have a more specific question about any of the terms I can answer it, but I don't currently know where you are struggling.

Comment: Isn't the answer ambiguous?
What makes `[1,2,3,1,4,1,2,3,4,5,1] -> [1,2,3,4,5,1]` the correct solution? Couldn't `[1,2,3,1,4,1,2,3,4,5,1] -> [4,1,2,3,4,5]` also be a valid solution?

Comment: @Alderath " In the case of a tie return any of the solutions."

Comment: @WheatWizard Sorry. My bad. Sometimes my brain silently discards small pieces of instructions...

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ẇœ-QḊƊÐḟṪȯ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrajk3UDH@7oOtZ1eMLDHfMf7lx1Yv3/w@1HJz3cOeP//2hDHQUjHQUgaQxkxAIA)**

#### How?

```
Ẇœ-QḊƊÐḟṪȯ - Link: list, A
Ẇ          - substrings (well, non-empty ones) sorted by length then left to right
      Ðḟ   - filter discard those for which this is truthy:
     Ɗ     -   last three links as a monad:
   Q       -     distinct values
 œ-        -     multiset difference - remove one of each value from A
    Ḋ      -     dequeue - remove one from this list if there are any
                         - [] is falsey
        Ṫ  - tail - one of, or the, longest one
                  - unless A was [] in which case zero
         ȯ - logical OR with A - replace that zero with []
```

---

Alternatively, `Ẇœ-QLỊƲƇṪȯ`.

Comment: Nice use of `Ḋ` and `Ðḟ` - I had [this 11 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrZAH5VHDTNsfY5tOtb@cOeqE@v/H25/1LTm///o6FgdhWhDHSMdYxgDygQzgNgEJm4I4sJVA7kmOhCWiY6pjmFsLAA)

Comment: `Þ` works with your 11 too, but still need the `ȯ` to handle the empty list unfortunately.

Comment: What is the definition of `bytes` in Code Golf? `len(bytes("Ẇœ-QḊƊÐḟṪȯ", 'utf-8')) == 22`

Comment: @batisteo the raw source-code itself is 10 bytes, the representation above is just making use of a mapping -- Jelly's code-page, which is linked to by the "[bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)" in the header. Hence counting the bytes of the Unicode characters you see above is not the source-code byte count for scoring purposes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [xash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95594/xash)*

```
⊇.ọtᵐ×≤2&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FXu97D3b0lD7dOODz9UecSI7Xi//@jDXWMdIx1DHVMdCAsEx1THcPY/xEA)

#### Explanation

We're looking for a sublist in which each element occurs only once, except that one element may occur twice.

Makes use of [this very helpful tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231602/16766) from [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string).

```
⊇.ọtᵐ×≤2&s
            The input
⊇           Sublist (not necessarily contiguous), trying longest first
 .          The result is the output
  ọ         Generate a list of [element, count] pairs
   tᵐ       Get the last element of each pair (list of counts)
     ×      Product
      ≤2    Is less than or equal to 2
        &s  Also, the output is a contiguous sublist of the input
```

Comment: 9b by checking if product of the occurrence counts is less or equal 2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FXu97D3b0lD7dOODz9UecSo0cdy///jzbUMdIx1jHUMdGBsEx0THUMY/9HAAA "Brachylog – Try It Online")

Comment: The `&s` is necessary so that the output is a *contiguous* sublist of the input, but that still saves 2 bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,...r)=>a[new Set(a).size+1]?f(...r,a.slice(1),a.pop()&&a):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY8xT8QwDIX3/gpPV1uXRiqUhVPKxMIAw42l0lklhaBcGzVRkUD89tJeWgSD5fe@Z9nyO4/sm8G4kHX9i56mViELKeVAquSq0x9w1AGZpDefep/Xdy0uqWDprWk05jRL1zuk3Y7plqegfWjYaw8KTklVQ1ZCVSdVLq7EdXRRRvQPRnzpcxUx2Eyczxe3BdGsu2dXiKgKcSPyP7dWkJxkGMwZ52ecNQHT5y4leWaHFlQJdsNZueJxwQ/Hp0fpePAaRyI6JL8fyrYf7rl5Q6yMAF3TMv6VADR953urpe1fUYNS0KIh2EOaioucl3zTYfoB)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,*r:len(l)>1+len({*l})and f(*r,l[1:],l[:-1])or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BroIwEEX3fMWEDR0cTKq4IYEfQRZVS2wy1qY0L3l5ed@OxYrRRaf33LlpZ9xvuN7tfp7HltXtdFHAVPqGtRWMndws4q/kf1T2AqMoPXEvmyHWppID3j3wPMYa9BTOatJgLOR5nvUDVB30Q9ZL2tE@UZLJ@jKT/bzjqVNjhZSXC62NBK@3I9WUVE0Hkh9/vYwsTrSdgjdO4HZybIIojrbAJgMwBBpauCkn9I9iem@yBquuQIxB540NYhQGoW1BEywS5wc)

Yet another question solved with same pattern?

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##VY/BjsIgFEX3/YqXbgrNqwlaN03aH0EWzEgjyRMJJSZmMv56pWKNLoB77r15gL/F08Xt5nnsSZ9/jhoI69DRQLJr7mQc@6vpnyvtjjCyOiBJ0SlcUqH4JQDNY9qjmeKvngxYB2VZFlJBM4BUhRS4xV2mLLP1ZWb7eabV5mCF3BcLrUGG1@xELWbV4h7Fx10vo0gv2kwxWM/4ZvJkI6sOruJdAWARDPRw1p6ZqyZ8/2QtNkPFeSr6YF1kI7Mc@h4MwiL5/AA) on the Python one I think.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 11 bytes

```
ẆµĠẈ’SỊµƇṪȯ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLhuobCtcSg4bqI4oCZU+G7isK1xofhuarIryIsIsOH4oKsIiwiIixbIltbXSwgWzEsMiwzXSwgWzEsMiwyLDNdLCBbMiwyLDMsMiw0XSwgWzEsMiwxLDMsMl0sIFsxLDIsMywxLDQsMSwyLDMsNCw1LDFdXSJdXQ==)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

```
ẆµĠẈ’SỊµƇṪȯ   Main Link
Ẇ             all sublists
 µ     µƇ     filter
  Ġ           - group indices of equal elements
   Ẉ          - length of each group
    ’         - subtract one from each length
     S        - sum of these (total number of duplicate elements)
      Ị       - is this insigificant? (between -1 and 1)
         Ṫ    take the last (longest) element
          ȯ   logical OR; if the output is 0 (only happens if input
              is []), return the input instead, which fixes [] being
              output as 0
```

Comment: `ȯ` will do the job at the end there.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Feel like I'm missing a trick here :\

```
ã fÈÊÉ¶Xâ ÊÃiU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yBmyMrJtljiIMrDaVU&input=WzEsMiwxLDMsMl0)

Comment: [12?](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yDxymzIp1riIMrE&input=WzEsMiwxLDMsMl0)

Comment: Also [10](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=4yBsyKda4iDKxA&input=WzEsMiwxLDMsMl0) could work if longer sublists are at the end but not sure

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:len(l)>1+len({*l})and max(f(l[1:]),f(l[:-1]),key=len)or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BasQwDEX3PoWZldUqAXfSTSC5SMjCJQ4VVWwTm6Gh9OypXc9AuxB670tI4Ujv3l3Pcx3YbG@LkdyzdYph1M8Fvp74G4xb5GY@1ap40v0MWKBvdKYPewx5D/wu@aQt@D3JeEQh1pJIcsXamBZy7W7NwuRsVNALSeiHzQRlb4aR2xiYkro04wVAyLCTS4ryIwL0cE6zbEY5zWLS@ILXahVr9C@s8W/P1dXBQ@q@LvYYVLnfztZhpQ5fUf/5dQ9@AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>108</s>   83 bytes

```hs
f l@(u:q)|0:(0<$l)<[0|x<-l,y<-q,x==y]=f(init$l)!f q
f q=q
a!b|(a<$a)>(a<$b)=a|1>0=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYnBCsIwEAXv/Yot5JDAFpJaLyVb/I@SQ4oGgzE1WqGF/HusePXwmGHe1b5ulxBKcRBO/N0nkWXPpWZB6FHmVTcBN90kXIk2Q4776Jf9rB2kah@lytZT5lYzK4YvJkE2q0HSVO7WRyA4zxXA4@njAgzcqLDFA7bmT1TY4c86PKIy5QM)

- Thanks to @Wheat Wizard for saving so many many bytes!

`g` : counts duplicates.  -> moved to list comprehension in *f* by Wheat Wizard , the tricky part is here and deserves an explanation

```hs
f(u:q)|
(0<$q)       list 0s for each element 
<            compared to
[0|x<-q,y<-q,x==y] list of 0s for each equal pairs in the powerset
```

Note that we use tail so that one potential dupe is already counted and the lists must be the same, if not there is more than 1 dupe, in that case we search.. Else we skip this and f q=q match giving the result.

a`!`b : selects longer list.
`f`*list* : if *list* is not ok choose from head or tail else return it

Comment: [96](https://tio.run/##JcZBDoMgEEDRPacYExaQzsJp7cY4XsSYiokgKZKm4o6709oufv5bzf5cQijFqqMNOlPnfmCrfPRJnq4sBPGNgzDVnJXppNH9uVmzydTXPAun1jZp3o9toLxOS1i2KY0XB0k4eHBdNuMjMLzePiaQYAfCK96QsMG/GrwjjeUD "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: It doesn't work because `0` is a num.  You can use `()` instead which it likes but `a` is shorter.

Comment: Yeah, it's an easy fix though: [80](https://tio.run/##FYrLCsMgEADv@YoNeFDYgvZxKW5@JOSwQqXSVLptCgn47yYeZuYyT/69HvNca9T/u5iirVdi/GjL6k@CW9NKtE0UdcppUe3qI0h3QNJxH4pmr9gMLcEQFzdYCvXNKQPB55vyAgri6PCMF7xiq8Mbuqnu "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: I think that my trick actually does not work.  It fails on `[1,2,3,2]`.  I incorrectly assumed that the solution would always start with one of the elements in the pair.  Fixing it costs [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYvLCsMgEADv@YoNeFDYgvZxCW5@JOSwQqVSKzX1kID/buNlZi7z4t/7GWNrHnLVk56ktiIru@i620vGo2MnOlbysnCIkNXoZUihnDWcF@WBR1clW8Fq7nKKuJpZk2sfDgkIvltIBQT4xeAVb3jHboMPNGv7Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Wheat Wizard I managed to use the trick partially, at least I think it works

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 78 bytes

```
M!&r`.*\d\b
.*\b(\d+)(?=.*,\1\b),(.*\b(\d+)\b.*,\3\b)
$2
O$^`((,)|\d)+
$#2
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w31dRrShBTysmJSaJC0glacSkaGtq2NvqaenEGMYkaepowEVjkkCCxkBBLhUjLn@VuAQNDR3NmpgUTW0uFWUjLkOgcf@5DHWMdIzBJIgGk0BsAhYxBLEhKoBsEx0Iy0THVMcQAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
M!&r`.*\d\b
```

Take all of the suffixes.

```
.*\b(\d+)(?=.*,\1\b),(.*\b(\d+)\b.*,\3\b)
$2
```

Truncate them at the second last duplicate. (Since we need this longish regex to check for two pairs/three of a kind, it turns out to be golfier to truncate the prefixes than to filter on all sublists.)

```
O$^`((,)|\d)+
$#2
```

Sort by descending number of elements.

```
1G`
```

Take the first.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
≔⟦⟧ηＦθ«⊞υιＷ‹¹ΣＥυ›μ⌕υλ≔Φυμυ¿›ＬυＬη≔Ｉυη»η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4/D4IwEMVn@BQ3tsk5oDgxGRNcMCFxJAwNFtqkgPaPDsbPXlvExJte7vfeu@sE093MlPcHY@QwkaZFELRI@1kDuVN4pUntjCAOQYZ18hRScSAVN4ZkCBc3kjO7RXzSnFmuyYhQyukaV4ouA2t3KVU0BDBSBBfrZA/kF6z4NNhwKbBVir/wkRm7sPjdO621nGwwFN43TYZb3GGGOX5VjnvM2tZvHuoD) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Start with no longest sublist.

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the input terms.

```
⊞υι
```

Append the term to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｗ‹¹ΣＥυ›μ⌕υλ
```

While the current sublist contains more than one duplicate...

```
≔Φυμυ
```

... remove the first term from the sublist.

```
¿›ＬυＬη
```

If the sublist is longer than the longest sublist so far, then...

```
≔Ｉυη
```

... save a copy of the sublist (because we're going to push to the original, and we need to cast it to string anyway).

```
»η
```

Output the longest sublist (which we already cast to string above).

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
f=->l,s=1{l[-s]&&f[l,s+1]||l.each_cons(s).find{|q|q.uniq[s-2]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5Hp9jWsDonWrc4Vk0tLRrI1TaMranJ0UtNTM6IT87PK9Yo1tRLy8xLqa4prCnUK83LLIwu1jWKra39X6CQFh1tqGOkY6xjomMKomNj/wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 28 bytes

```
su<-{f:)-]g_2<=j{1==}al&&}fe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@TV12U@L@41Ea3Os1KUzc2Pd7Ixjar2tDWtjYxR02tNi31f21u9P9oQx0jHeNYBS4wA8oEM4DYJBYibAjiQdnGQJ6JDoRlomOqYxgLAA)

```
su           # All substrings from shortest to longest
<-           # Reverse (longest first)
{
 f:          # Frequency list as (count, val) sorted by count
 )-]         # Map head (get counts)
 g_          # Split into head + tail
 2<=         # Head is 2 or 1
 j           # Swap
 {1==}al     # Tails all 1s
 &&          # Logical AND
}fe          # Find the first element for which
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 162 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 148 bytes** by replacing two `function` occurrences with `\`s.

```r
function(v,a=apply(combn(rep(seq(v),2),2),2,function(x,t=table(k<-v[x[1]:x[2]]))if(x[1]<=x[2]&all(t%in%1:2)&sum(t==2)<2)k))"if"(sum(v),a[order(-lengths(a))[1]],v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RDoIgFIbve4pWq52z4QVkN016EcYFGZSL0JScPb2BVlYbbOf7fuCn7g3vzd3lvigdtERxVVX2AXl5PTiodQWNvkGLhI2LfM52xHOvDlbDJUta0Qkqd51gUiIWBiJmPPJaWQt@VbgV3TFcN/creM4ZZgwviIvCLCC6UKFEWR91DYnV7uTPDSjE8IwkLfYGckBczpP9XMhZJBo@s3mrASb/l3yyYQw7facvnG7SKKZ0wK@@IFIyTinZEvrTPyrZPwE)

I was hoping for some ingenious answer from better [R](https://www.r-project.org/) golfers here, but it looks like I have to post my boring straightforward one first for some motivation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
f[s=___,Longest@a:s,s]/;Total[Counts@{a}-1]<2=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tutg2Pj5exyc/Lz21uMQh0apYpzhW3zokvyQxJ9o5vzSvpNihOrFW1zDWxsg28X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V3WtDle1oY6RjjGMAWWCGUBsAhM3BHHhqoFcEx0Iy0THVMewlqv2PwA)

Input and output a `Sequence` of values.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 48 bytes

```
Last@*Select[Total[Counts@#-1]<2&]@*Subsequences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexuMRBKzg1JzW5JDokvyQxJ9o5vzSvpNhBWdcw1sZILRYoW5pUnFpYmpqXnFr8P6AoM68kWlnXLs1BOVatLjg5Ma@umqu6Voer2lDHSMcYxoAywQwgNoGJG4K4cNVArokOhGWiY6pjWMtV@x8A)

Input and output a list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 77 bytes

```
[ f suffix all-subseqs [ histogram values 1 v-n Σ 2 < ] find-last nip sift ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BTgMxDEX3PcW/wIw0pRUSsEdsukFdVV2Y1Gkj0iTEzqgFcRruw5WGtCM6C1vP/v6WviWjMQ/r15fV8wOEPwoHwzJRyyfNJDiSHq6tFSV1os4ISCSaUWt7vnwSvHMO7MddCc7EHSNlVj2n7IJiz4EzefdZv8QgeJzNvvBdq8Mcdzf655HmWNyU7jpPjq5qIy2wrDQpl6thAwsp1roTyPtGylvNJtjgUEPEfaYjevKlZu7QNwG/P9X3hC2sC7vGkyiCSxBnFdvhHoFS8me0AuOZ8vAH)

### Explanation

- `f suffix ... sift` Work around the fact that `all-subseqs` blows up on an empty input. Add `f` to the input and remove it with `sift` at the end. (This doesn't change anything since we're only adding one.)
- `all-subseqs [ ... ] find-last nip` Find the last/largest subsequence of the input that returns true when the given quotation is called on it.

The quotation to `find-last` works by taking a histogram of the input, subtracting 1 from all the counts, taking the sum, and checking whether the sum is less than two. For instance:

```
             ! { 2 2 3 2 4 }
histogram    ! H{ { 2 3 } { 3 1 } { 4 1 } }
values       ! { 3 1 1 }
1 v-n        ! { 2 0 0 }
Σ            ! 2
2 <          ! f
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Razetime*

```
►LfoεṠ-uQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0XT5p@ee2Pty5QLc08P///9GGOkY6xjqGOiY6EJaJjqmOYSwA)

```
►           # output the (first) element with maximum...
 L          # ...length...
            # ...from among:
         Q  # all contiguous sublists, 
  fo        # filtered by:
      Ṡ-    # the difference between...
        u   # ...itself and unique elements of itself...
    ε       # ...has length 1.
```

Comment: -1: `►LfoεṠ-uQ`, `ε` checks size of the list as well

Comment: @Razetime - Thanks!  I need to re-read the docs, I guess...

Comment: @Razetime - BTW: last day to try to crack [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241744/95126)...

Comment: oh, i see. I did not notice this thread.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 80 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
l=length
head.sortOn(\x->(l(x\\nub x)>1,-l x)).(tails=<<).inits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BDoIwEETv/Yoe26Q0KeKNcvKo8QOAmBqLbCiV0DXh72sF9LB5M7Ob2d6EwToXI4zTa0Z6MmjkGQISp531T@xJp3trHjKk9dWzZskq5tjSNP59pwuvlMhcIpcMDbigy5JL8IAhog0YqKZ13YpaiVwcdm5qZZpiT9XX/S6TK8SmCnEU6p/nbUvIaMCn4tFMlxtl0wweZcfp@jB@AA)

Get all infixes, sort by `(invalid, -length)`, return the first one.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```javascript
f=(X,a)=>X[h=new Set([w,...x]=X).size+1]?(a=f(x),b=f(X,X.pop()),a[h]?a:b):X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BCsIwDIbvPoXHBGOhWi@DuofwEig9dLNzk7EOO9zw5eumN3GHkPB9/0/u7uli@Wj6Yd@Fq0@p0sDkUJ/Z1Lrz4/biBzAjCSEmqxlFbF5@J20OTlcwIRXzYmLRhx4QyZna5i4rMONUhi6G1os23KACYxE3P0jSgY4r/L/58HnUSksudu3TbBV9L0UnkksuJX4D)

AnttiP's idea, can't read golfing language so don't know if that's source

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 89 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,h,L=0,a=x.filter(y=x=>!(y[x]=h+=[y[x]])[20]&&++L),b=x[0]?f(x.slice(1)):[])=>b[L]?b:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BDoIwEEX33sINmYaRUMQNycAFuEHTRcFWMQ01QEw5fQXdGbuY5Oe9/zMP9VJzPw3P5TS6qw7BEHi8Y0s5KvKZGeyiJ1jJU32EVXhJ95TEHiQTRS6TJE1bhh15kcvGgM9mO/QaOGOVkIzqTrSy6SoVejfOzurMuhsY2Bw7/CCOBZ4j/L/58O3KyIrvNvZpsyV@U4kX5HsvRNQb)

Is it usual to be 6-8x longer than golfing language or this is quite golfable?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒʒgyÙg-!}éθ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTk9IrD89M11WsPbzy3I7//6MNdYx0jHUMdUx0ICwTHVMdw1gA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o5NOTUqvPDwzXVex9vDKczv@6/yPjo7VUYg21DHSMYYxoEwwA4hNYOKGIC5cNZBrogNhmeiY6hgiJIxiYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ        # Get all sublists of the (implicit) input-list
 ʒ       # Filter this list of sublists by:
  g      #  Get the length of the sublist
   y     #  Push the sublist again
    Ù    #  Uniquify its items
     g   #  Pop and push the length of this uniquified list as well
      -  #  Subtract the lengths from one another
       ! #  Check if this is either 0 or 1 by taking the faculty, which will
         #  result in [1,1,2,6,24,120,...] for [0,1,2,3,4,5,...] respectively,
         #  and only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E
 }é      # After the filter: sort the remaining sublists from shortest to longest
   θ     # Pop and keep just the last (longest)
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```